# Using any in affirmative sentences, plural or singular?

Tags: possessive-adjectives

Is the following sentence correct?

> Any college student interested in working in the Library this summer should send **his** details to the Dean as soon as possible.

I am particularly interested in whether I should use their or his (assuming all students are male).

If the correct use is **his**, do we use their when we change it to "Any college students"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To mean *indefinite quantities*, we use **any** with *plural nouns* or with *uncountable nouns* in *negative* and *interrogative* sentences :

> *"Have you eaten any mangoes?"*

> *"I have not eaten any mangoes."*

2. To mean *"it doesn't matter which or what"*, we use **any** with *all types of nouns* in *affirmative* sentences :

> *"Any college **student** interested in working in the Library this summer should send **his** details to the Dean as soon as possible."*

Or,

> *"Any college **students** interested in working in the Library this summer should send **their** details to the Dean as soon as possible."*